# I wanted to create a project on Xcode that shows ETA of a download given the file size and download speed

Tags: swift, xcode, download

Below is the link to my app design. I have not done any coding yet. Im jut a beginner taking some courses on Mobile App Development. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Csso.jpg

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code outsourcing service.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to study **URLSessionDownloadDelegate**. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background). Following delegate method help you to achieve your goal.

```
extension YourViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        print("did write data: \(bytesWritten)")
    }


    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        print("task did complete")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `Alamofire` For this:**

```
self.request =  Alamofire.request("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4").downloadProgress{ (progress) in
                print(progress.fractionCompleted) //Fraction or Progress of Download
                self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted) //You can show that in a ProgressView like this
                self.lblProgressView.text = String(format: "%.0f%%", progress.fractionCompleted * 100)
                }.responseData{ (response) in
                    print(response)
                    if let data = response.result.value {
                        do {
                            print(data)
                        } catch {
                            print("Something went wrong!")
                        }

                    }
            }
```

Hope it helps.